# How to resolve a generic type service from the DependencyInjection at Asp.net Core runtime

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, type-inference

I am dealing with a WeChat project that post XML message to my server. The message could be any one of several types. Hence I first deserialize the message to corresponding object with a base "WxMessage", and then return the object to a dispatcher, which will find out a correct message handler to handle the message. The handlers, corresponding to each type of messages, were registered to the DependencyInjection of Asp.net core 2.1 with a IWxMessageHandler<> interface.

```
services.AddScoped<IWxMessageHandler<WxMessage_Image>, WxMessageHandler_Image>();
services.AddScoped<IWxMessageHandler<WxMessage_Text>, WxMessageHandler_Text>();
services.AddScoped<IWxMessageHandler<WxMessage_File>, WxMessageHandler_File>();
```

This is the message service:

```
    public async Task<string> Handle(string messageBody)
    {
        var reply = default(WxMessage);

        using (var deserial = new WxInMessageDeserializer())
        {
            var deserializedModel =  deserial.Parse(messageBody);

            reply = (WxReplyMessage_Text) await HandleMessage(deserializedModel);
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(BuildXmlContent(reply));
    }

    public async Task<WxMessage> HandleMessage<TMessage>(TMessage message) 
    {
        var _handler = _serviceProvider.GetService<IWxMessageHandler<TMessage>>();
        ......
    }
```

However it failed to resolve the correct implement of IWxMessageHandler<> as the WxInMessageDeserializer return a base object of WxMessage:

```
        var result = default(WxMessage);
        switch (_msgTYpe)
            {
                case "text": result = (WxMessage_Text)new XmlSerializer(typeof(WxMessage_Text))
                        .Deserialize(new StringReader(rawMessage));
                    break;
                case "image": result = (WxMessage_Image)new XmlSerializer(typeof(WxMessage_Image))
                        .Deserialize(new StringReader(rawMessage));
                    break;
                case "voice": result = (WxPushMessage_Voice)new XmlSerializer(typeof(WxPushMessage_Voice))
                        .Deserialize(new StringReader(rawMessage));
                    break;
                ......
                case "file": result = (WxMessage_File)new XmlSerializer(typeof(WxMessage_File))
                        .Deserialize(new StringReader(rawMessage));
                    break;
            }
        return result;
```

I guess this is a limitation of the C# Type Inferencing, as the result was correct when I use explicit calling method like HandleMessage(somemessage). Currently I am solving this issue by revolving a list of all services and then select the one I want:

```
        var type = typeof(TMessage);
        var _handler = _handlers
            .Where(h => h.GetHandlingType().Equals(message.GetType()))
            .FirstOrDefault();
        var result = _handler.Handle(message);
        return await result;
```

Yet I am wondering if there is any better solutions to this issue. 
Thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: How about rather having an `IWxMessageHandlerFactory` that you add to `services` and inject that into your message service? The factory can take the TMessage as a parameter to a `Create()` method and return the correct type of handler.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that generic types are evaluated at compile time. So even if your `HandleMessage` is a generic `HandleMessage<TMessage>(TMessage message)`, the type of `TMessage` that is used is not a runtime type.

The way you call your method is like this:

```
var deserializedModel = deserial.Parse(messageBody);
reply = (WxReplyMessage_Text) await HandleMessage(deserializedModel);
```

So the compile-time type of `deserializedModel` determines what type will be used for the generic type argument `TMessage`.

Since `Parse` is not generic itself, it will likely return a base type, and that base type will then be used for `HandleMessage`. As such, inside `HandleMessage`, `TMessage` will be that base type and the call to `GetService<IWxMessageHandler<TMessage>>` will use that base type to retrieve the handler service instance.

If you want to get the actual handler, you will have to retrieve the *concrete* service type from the service provider. And in order to do that from a run-time type of your message object, you will need to use reflection to retrieve and construct that type:

```
public async Task<WxMessage> HandleMessage(IWxMessage message) 
{
    var messageType = message.GetType();
    var messageHandlerType = typeof(IWxMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);

    var handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(messageHandlerType);

    // …
}
```

This assumes that you have a base type `IWxMessage` for the message and makes the `HandleMessage` method non-generic. Instead, the handler type will be resolved at compile-time from the concrete message type. Note that you should also have some base interface for your message handler that allows you to call a method on all types (ideally just taking an `IWxMessage`), otherwise you will also have to use reflection to call the handler.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Poke. I have successfully resolved the correct handler by your code. However the handler was the type of Object and I have to use dynamic to go on handling the message:

                  var handler = _provider.GetService(messageHandlerType);
            dynamic d = handler;
            var handlingstxnResult =d.Handle(message);
Is there a better way to deal with it other than dynamic?

Comment: As mentioned at the end of my answer, your handler should have a base interface so you can cast the handler to that type and cast the `Handle` method on it. I.e. `var handler = (IWxMessageHandler)_serviceProvider.GetService(…);` where `IWxMessageHandler` is a non-generic interface of your handlers that take a `IWxMessage`. Otherwise, if you don’t have such a base type, then you will have to use reflection to call the `Handle` message on the handler object.

Comment: Thanks @poke , I will take a try.