# Json deserialize generics

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize objects using generics but consumers can't pick them up even though they look completely fine.

```
    private readonly IContainer _container = Ioc.GetContainer();

    public async Task Test()
    {
        var command = new TestCommand();

        var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(command);

        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializeObject, command.GetType());

        await Process(message);

        await Process(command);
    }

    private async Task Process<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
        await _container.Resolve<IMessageDispatcher>().Dispatch(message);
    }

    public async Task Dispatch<TMessage>(TMessage message)
    {
        using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var consumers = scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IMessageConsumer<TMessage>>>().ToList();

            if(consumers.Any() == false) throw new Exception($"No consumer for message {message.GetType().Name}");

            foreach (var consumer in consumers)
            {
                await consumer.Consume(message, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IMessageConsumer<TMessage>
    {
      Task Consume(TMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    }
```

My message fails to find a consumer but the command variable does? Even though these objects look identical?

Comment: There is much code there that complicates things including the use of an IoC container. Please simplify this down to a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `variable` message below will be of compile time type `object` and *runtime* type `TMessage`. For generics type binding to work, the type needs to be possible to evaluate at compile time.

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(serializeObject, command.GetType());
```

You will either need to Deserialize to a more specific generic type:

```
var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestCommand>(serializeObject);
```

or check the type at runtime in some way, for example:

```
if(message is TestCommand)

...
```

Comment: This is what I thought but was hoping to avoid with having around 30 messages

Comment: There seems to be ways to deal with your problem (to dynamically create a MessageDispatcher with a generic type parameter for your command type): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250059/1257728 Not sure what dependency injection you are using, but I think that it might be possible to rewrite the example in the link to fit your scenario